# AutoImport в PhpStorm не работает (react-app)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, intellij-idea, phpstorm

Делаю реакт-приложение и создаю компонент, который я экспортирую по дефолту.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После чего захожу в родительский компонент и добавляю его в верстку, надеясь, что после добавления, auto import сработает, но он его не видит

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если сделать в обратном порядке, то есть сначала проимпортировать, а потом добавлять в компонент, то все работает, но ведь автоимпорт для этого и нужен, чтобы самому дописаться...

Настройки в PhpStorm следующие

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Тот же самый проект в VS Code с плагином auto import отрабатывает на ура.
Заранее спасибо)

Comment: Возможно, это баг phpstorm, попробуйте адресовать ваш вопрос в [багтрекер jetbrains](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI).

Answer (score 3):

1. Наведи мышку на нужный тебе элемент, далее зажми `Alt+Enter` и выбери как на скриншоте:

   [image: скриншот]
2. Экспорт по дефолту плохая практика, приучай себя экспортировать правильно:

   `export { TestComp }` вместо `export default TestComp`